# Where is Linguistics Meta gone .... long time passing

Tags: support

It may be one of those cases when I look for my glasses, actually sitting on my nose, but ...

My pages on http://linguistics.stackexchange.com no longer seem to carry a link to http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com

I had to take a devious route to come back to it.

Is the problem with my brain, or with the site (which seems very quiet lately)

Actually, I just found a link that shows up when I click on the upper-left StackExchange logo. But I thought I had used before a direct meta-user link, like those found for other topics on SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new top bar design has rolled out to all Q&A sites on the network.  Our users have put together a quick list of where the links moved here:
[New top bar quick reference guide / Where has the link to <X> gone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210186/new-top-bar-quick-reference-guide-where-has-the-link-to-x-gone)